# Javascript gmail API convenience wrapper\parser

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

GMAIL API endpoint `gmail.users.messages.get` returns comprehensive email object.

It has all type of headers, body, attachments etc, etc.
It is usually nested with many body\parts, some of them are embedded directly in the object, some has to be fetched separately like attachmentId.

I'm looking for JS library to quickly get `BODY` of email.
Better if it can also get `attachments` and some other properties like `to`, `from` etc.
Getting `body` reliably proved to be very difficult. It can be located in different parts of the returned object. There are many ways it can be encoded and I'm learning more and more.

I'm not looking for some simple
Use `Buffer(email.payload.body.data).toString('base64')` answer.
It is not going to work.
I need reliable way to extract body from ~10000 emails in my account.
From all different types of them.

Any library for that?
Something like `mailparser` but for this message format.